# Postgres: copy from 2 different DBs for identical tables

Tags: postgresql, aws, pgadmin, pg-dump

I have two identical DBs, under the same port and host. (they both `postgres` DBs and on `AWS`) I want to create a script\write any query (even though it is not possible to create a query that use data from 2 different dbs) to copy from the production db (alt_monitoring) to the test db (test), but only the new records - records that were added to the database in the last few days and are not yet in the test DB, without creating duplicates with what exists there (some of the tables are very heavy).

How can I do so on `AWS` \ `pgAdmin` \ any other way?

I tried with `pg_dump` but the only way I found out is to delete all rows from existing table with  `--verbose --clean --if-exists`

Comment: Add a `created_at` column that allows you to identify new rows, then extract and load those rows.

Comment: how? I have many tables and I want to do it automatically with a script. Is it possible?

Comment: No, because the script won't know what is new.

Comment: Look into logical replication.